# What does the ^ symbol mean when passed into the .where() funtion?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Could someone please explain what does the `^^^` symbol does when passed into the `np.where` function?

[image: Video explaining np.where usage with Pandas dataframe]

Does it just represents the number of arguments that should be passed in?

Comment: It's just a placeholder. As if there were an arrow drawn there, pointing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it just represents the number of arguments that should be passed in?

Yes.

It's being used in this case to point to the first call to `np.where`.

You can see for yourself:

```
$ python3
Python 3.9.7 (default, Oct 22 2021, 13:39:39) 

>>> np.where(^^^)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    np.where(^^^)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: what do you mean to call np.where ? i tried same code and it was syntax error

Comment: @Yefet, there are two calls to `np.where` in the image. The first one is merely showing the arguments that will be passed to one, while the second one is showing how it will be called in conjunction with the dataframe. The `^^^` in the second call are acting as arrows indicating that the arguments to the first call (which the arrows are pointing to) are used as the arguments to the second call, in replacement of the arrows.

Comment: so its just for indicating that? not actual rare operation/syntax which i did not about?

Comment: No. It's certainly not, because that's _completely_ invalid syntax in Python. The tutorial really shouldn't do that. It's bad practice to use invalid syntax to denote stuff like that.